# Is it possible to add ref to the props.children elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a **Form** and **Input** components, which are rendered as below.

```
<Form>
   <Field />
   <Field />
   <Field />
</Form>
```

**Form** component will act as wrapper component here and **Field** component ref are not being set here. I want iterate through **props.children** in **Form** Component and want to assign a ref attribute to each children. Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need `Form` to inject your refs with `React.Children` and `React.cloneElement` APIs:

```
const FunctionComponentForward = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div ref={ref}>Function Component Forward</div>
));

const Form = ({ children }) => {
  const childrenRef = useRef([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Form Children", childrenRef.current);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) =>
        React.cloneElement(child, {
          ref: (ref) => (childrenRef.current[index] = ref)
        })
      )}
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Form>
      <div>Hello</div>
      <FunctionComponentForward />
    </Form>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Vanilla-React-Template (forked)]

Notice: Cloning children makes it hard to tell how the data flows through your app. Try one of the [alternatives](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement#alternatives).

Comment: I am getting this warning index.js:1 Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Comment: In my example I pass ref to `div`, when you pass to function component you need to use `forwardRef` or use other prop like `innerRef` and pass the ref.

Comment: Ive added an example, you can just look for "passing a ref to function component".

Comment: What if I don't have control over the child component?

Comment: @DPA you need to be more specific, try asking a new question

Comment: `cloneElement` is fragile, suggested is to use passing component as props. https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement#alternatives

Answer (score 6):

You can map children create new instance of component based on it using one of two ways showed in [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement).

- With `React.Children.map` and `React.cloneElement` (this way, key and ref from original element are preserved)
- Or only with `React.Children.map` (Only ref from original component is preserved)

```
function useRefs() {
  const refs = useRef({});

  const register = useCallback((refName) => ref => {
    refs.current[refName] = ref;
  }, []);

  return [refs, register];
}

function WithoutCloneComponent({children, ...props}) {

 const [refs, register] = useRefs(); 

 return (
    <Parent>
     {React.Children.map((Child, index) => (
       <Child.type 
         {...Child.props}
         ref={register(`${field-${index}}`)}
         />
    )}
    </Parent>
 )
}

function WithCloneComponent({children, ...props}) {

 const [refs, register] = useRefs(); 

 return (
    <Parent>
     {
       React.Children.map((child, index) => React.cloneElement(
         child, 
         { ...child.props, ref: register(`field-${index}`) }
       )
    }
    </Parent>
 )
}
```