# React forwardRef to children prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-forwardref

I have the following component that decides whether or not a component should be rendered based upon user permissions:

```js
const Can = forwardRef(({ requiredPermissions, children }, ref): null | JSX.Element => {
    const {
        user: { role },
        userPermissions,
    } = useAuth();

    return userHasPermission(role, userPermissions, requiredPermissions) ? children : null;
});

export default Can;
```

What I need to do is pass the `ref` to the child component that will be inside `Can` when the component is used.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I believe you need to use the `React.Children` API; see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63654496/is-it-possible-to-add-ref-to-the-props-children-elements) for examples.

Comment: As a typescript issue you would need to make sure that the type of the ref that you are passing is one that the child can accept.  If the child is a `div` then you must pass a ref to an `HTMLDivElement`.  This is rough.  It's easier if the `children` is a function.  `<Can>{MyComponent}</Can>` instead of `<Can><MyComponent/></Can>` as you can just call the child rather than cloning it.   `React.children` does not seem to have the right Typescript types in general.

Comment: Thank you Linda! I don’t mind converting it to a function. Would you like to take a stab at formulating an answer? I believe it would be closest to what I’m attempting to achieve.

Comment: @Sammy I'm struggling with how to make `Can` generic.  I can get the *contents* of the `forwardRef` to be generic but that's it. https://tsplay.dev/Nl08GN

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can. But you need to do two additional things:

1. You must be sure that only one child is being passed to the component. You can check it with the `React.Children.only` method.
2. Use `React.cloneElement` to pass `ref` to the child.

```js
const Can = forwardRef(({ requiredPermissions, children }, ref): null | JSX.Element => {
    const {
        user: { role },
        userPermissions,
    } = useAuth();

    return userHasPermission(role, userPermissions, requiredPermissions) 
        ? React.cloneElement(React.Children.only(children), {
            ref,
          }) 
        : null;
});

export default Can;
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought as much but this is why I asked the question relative to Typescript, since I keep getting this error: Argument of type 'boolean | {} | ReactChild | ReactPortal | null | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'.

Comment: Also, why are you passing the `...props` at the root level? Can't they be cloned with the element?

Comment: @Sammy You're right. `... props` are not required, but I didn't know the broader context and suggested you use it for more "flexibility". I could construct the answer differently :) I fix it.

Comment: @Sammy `children` can be functional component that returns `ReactElement` like `const Component = () => <p>Hello!</p>` or be `ReactElement` directly assigned to variable/constant like `const Component = <p>Hello!</p>;`. `React.Children.only` and `React.cloneElement` takes only elements or nodes (second example) and therefore TypeScript displays error.

Answer (score 2):

Use [React.Children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) and [React.cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) to pass the ref props to all child elements of `Can`.

Like this:

```js
const Can = forwardRef(
  ({ requiredPermissions, children }, ref): null | JSX.Element => {
    const {
      user: { role },
      userPermissions,
    } = useAuth();

    const childrenWithProps = () =>
      React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
        if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
          return (
            <React.Fragment>
              {React.cloneElement(child, {
                ref,
              })}
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        }
        return child;
      }) as React.ReactElement;

    return userHasPermission(role, userPermissions, requiredPermissions)
      ? childrenWithProps()
      : null;
  }
);

export default Can;
```

Comment: Thank you, but this gives this error: TS2322: Type '(() => DetailedReactHTMLElement<any, HTMLElement>[] | null | undefined) | null' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'.   Type '() => DetailedReactHTMLElement<any, HTMLElement>[] | null | undefined' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, key

Comment: Also, where does `customRef` come from?

Comment: Try wrapping each child with a `<React.Fragment />` to cast it to the expected return type. It can still be just `ref`, I used `customRef`  just to differentiate it from the `ref` that is being passed.

Comment: Also, we should also check if every child we map through is a valid `React.Element` before we clone it.

Comment: See update answer. Let me know if that helps