# How to create and pass ref to each child in props.children in typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript, react-ref

I'm building courosel animations with **react hooks** and **typescript**. I have `Slider` and `Slide` components.

```
<Slider>
  <Slide><div>1</div></Slide>
  <Slide><div>2</div></Slide>
<Slider/>
```

In `Slider` I need every ref passed to `Slide`. For example:

```
function Slider(props: PropsWithChidlren) {
   const slidesRefs:React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>[] = ...your logic...
   const childrenWithRefs = props.children.map(...your logic...)
   const slideAnimation = useSlideAnimation(slidesRefs)
   return <div>{childrenWithRefs}<div/>
}
```

**What I tried**:
[Is it possible to add ref to the props.children elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63654496/is-it-possible-to-add-ref-to-the-props-children-elements) and many things around this answer.
Also this way I receive an error: `Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.`

**How should I do that?**

Answer (score 0):

I did it with `React.forwardRef`:

```
// Slider.tsx
const Slider = (props:PropsWithChildren<{}>)=>{
     const slidesRefs = React.Children.map(
        props.children,
        (child: any, index: number) => {
            return useRef<HTMLDivElement>()
        }
    ) as React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>[]

    const slideAnimation = useSlideAnimation(slidesRefs)

    return 
      <div>{React.Children.map(props.children, 
              (child: any, index: number) => {
                  return React.cloneElement(child, { ref: slidesRefs [index] 
              }))
           }
     </div>
}

// Slide.tsx
const Slide = forwardRef((props: any, ref: any) => {
    return (
        <div className="min-w-full" ref={ref}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
})
```